# How to do security testing for API

Tags: api, security, sql-injection, sqlmap, wapiti

I have API like

"/getXXXX?ABC=X7TRYUV&Ab_DEF=true&Ab_XYZ=true&Ab_ExZ=ZXTY"

How can I check the vulnerability of the request parameters?

What type of strings  I can pass?

I ran the API in Wapiti and SQLMAP tool but found no issue.
manually i have tested it with by manipulating "Ab_ExZ=ZXTY" to 'CHR(91%2d1)'XTY

and It filter out the result as correct parameter where it should not filter out.

Thanks,
Bibek

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer to your question is it depends. There is a lot of useful information about injection style attacks available from [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_A1-Injection). The exact strings that you should use depend on the underlying technology of your solution and the characters e.g. terminating characters that are significant at each stage the data is processed.

A starting point for testing injection is to try to terminate the statement / command. For example in Oracle PL/SQL the characters `';` will work by the quote closing the string entry and the semi colon terminating the command. If the query is prone to injection attacks this will most likely give you an error from the database for a malformed query.

Obviously other databases will have slightly different syntax. Also worth considering is the underlying OS. If the input to the API is ending up being executed at the command line, is it Windows or Linux based? This will change the syntax that you want to try.

Finally, if data is being stored where is it then rendered? If it becomes rendered in a Web UI you can try inputing `<b>` obviously if your API allows this to be stored and then displayed to the user without being escaped you will see text in bold. This would indicate a second order injection attack. (The actual risk is when the data is retrieved rather than being sent).

I strongly recommend taking a look at the injection information available on OWASP's site. Including the [WebGoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/WebGoat_User_Guide_Introduction) examples where you can have a go at trying injection style testing against a deliberately vulnerable web site. The principles will translate nicely to the API testing.

Comment: To give absolute example strings to pass I will need to know the following. 1) The webserver (name and version) your API is running on. 2) The database (name and version) that is executing the end query. 3) The OS that the database and webserver are running on. 4) The expected functional behaviour of the request. Please could you update the problem statement with this information.